# Alternative to static methods

Tags: android, static, android-mediaplayer

I have a MediaPlayerService class with player methods and a "NowPlaying" Activity , i want to update the process , and best way for get player information ("getCurrentPosition" etc) is "static methods" and this Consumes a lot of battery power .

I want to update the process and save the battery , there is an Alternative to update process without static methods ?

Sorry for my bad eng .

Comment: static methods don't consume more battery, it's wrong. Search for the problem elsewhere

Comment: static methods don't cause battery drain!

Comment: I checked the source and it just came to my mind

Comment: static methods don't cause battery drain? How about static objects ?

Comment: you can use **broadcast receiver** or **interface** for this purpose, if you've problem with static methods

Comment: Static methods and static objects don't cause battery drain at all, the concept of static and battery drain is unrelated. What may cause a drain is if an object instance has some type of logic which is running none stop, such as a thread which performs whatever action continuously, but this problem would happen with any type of object as long as it has an instance, regardless if its declaration is static or not. Instead, the thing to consider with static objects and static methods is if there is a memory leak due to bad programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static method may lead to memory leak but its not bad for battery.
You can track any memory leak in your application by using this library([github.com/square](https://github.com/square/leakcanary))

If you want to use something else try BroadcastReceiver.